# Operaciones Aritméticas con Vectores en Java Dando como Resultado un Vector

Tags: java

Teniendo los siguientes vectores:

```
        int[] PuntosDistribucion = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
        int[] TiempoAsignado = {11, 14, 11, 12, 12, 10, 13, 15, 10, 10, 15, 12, 15, 12, 15, 10, 10, 14, 14, 12};
        int[] CajasAsignadas = {98, 86, 99, 89, 89, 96, 93, 87, 89, 92, 99, 90, 87, 96, 92, 85, 86, 97, 90, 98};
        int[] TiempoRegistrado = {10, 10, 15, 15, 12, 13, 12, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 10, 14, 13, 11, 13, 11};
        int[] CajasRegistradas = {100,86, 97, 93, 94, 93, 95, 85, 90, 90, 85, 89, 85, 93, 89, 89, 93, 99, 93, 99};
```

Debo realizar algunas operaciones índice a índice con ellos que me den como resultado otro vector.
Genero los vectores resultado en cero:

```
        int[] diferenciasCaja = {0};
        int[] diferenciasTiempo = {0};
        double[] eficiencia  = (0};
```

Como soy totalmente novato tanto en Java como en programación, trato de realizar las siguientes operaciones con ellos, obviamente se que así no dará ningún resultado:

```
        int[] diferenciasCaja = {arregloCajasAsignadas - arregloCajasRegistradas};
        int[] diferenciasTiempo = {arregloTiempoAsignado - arregloTiempoRegistrado};
        double[] eficiencia  = (double){(arregloTiempoAsignado - arregloTiempoRegistrado) / arregloTiempoAsignado * 100};
```

Creo que debo realizar las operaciones a través de un for, pero no tengo idea de como generarlo, pues solo conozco la manera de como se recorre un vector a través de un for para imprimir sus elementos.

¿Cómo puedo realizar las restas de los elementos de cada vector haciendo que den los resultados en otro vector índice por índice?... bueno... en el vector "eficiencia" es mas complejo aun por que además me toca dividirlos y multiplicarlos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < limite; i++)
{
   diferencias[i] = arregloA[i] - arregloB[i];
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es recorrer el arreglo y se va guardando en la **posición i** del **arreglo resultado** la resta del elemento que ocupa la **posición i** del **arreglo arregloA** con el elemento que ocupa la **posición i** del **arreglo arregloB**.

En el **ciclo for** se utilizó la **variable limite** la cual será el tamaño del arreglo, puedes usar **arreglo.Length()** para obtener este tamaño.

El arreglo donde se guardan las restas u operaciones debe tener el mismo tamaño que los arreglos que restas ej:
**int[tamaño] arreglo**, donde tamaño es el tamaño del arreglo.

La multiplicación y división sería

```
resultado[i] = ((arregloA[i] - arregloB[i]) / arregloA[i]) * 100;
```

Analiza este código y adáptalo al tuyo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Japv, con esto me guías mucho en las operaciones con vectores, tema que me tiene algo loco.